# Laravel migration - Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to run a migration for a table `inventories` that I have created with this migration:

```php
Schema::create('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('remote_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('local_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('local_type');
    $table->string('url')->nullable()->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I am trying to add a run a migration where I am adding a foreign key to the table:

```php
Schema::table('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('local_id')->references('id')->on('contents')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

But, I am getting an error when I try to run the migration:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`middleton`
>   .`#sql-5d6_162a`, CONSTRAINT `inventories_local_id_foreign` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`local_id`) REFERENCES `contents` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE     )
>   (SQL: alter table `inventories` add constraint
>   `inventories_local_id_foreign` foreign key (`local_id`) references
>   `contents` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`middleton`
>   .`#sql-5d6_162a`, CONSTRAINT `inventories_local_id_foreign` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`local_id`) REFERENCES `contents` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE     )

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably have some records in the `inventories` table with `local_id` that does not have corresponding `id` in the `contents` table, hence the error. You could solve it by one of the two ways:

- Run the migration with `foreign_key_checks` turned off. This will disabled the foreign key constraints for the existing rows (if that's what you want). It's documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)
- Insert only those records that have corresponding `id` field in `contents` table. You can use `INSERT INTO.. WHERE EXISTS` query to filter the records out, and insert only those records.

Comment: Yes, once I deleted all tables and run all migrations at once, then it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by adding `nullable` to field:

```php
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->integer('some_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('some_id')->references('id')->on('other_table');
    ...
});
```

Note that after migration all existed rows will have `some_id = NULL`.

**UPD**:

Since Laravel 7 there is more short way to do the same thing:

```php
$table->foreignId('some_id')->nullable()->constrained();
```

It is also very important that `nullable` goes BEFORE `constrained`.

More info you can find here, in [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: This is important to remember for existing databases, thanks for sparking my memory!

Comment: This error occurs because SQL expects the foreign id column to have data, but since we didn't mention that the field can be nullable, it throws the error. Thanks for this.