# can't update a child row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I created the `lessons` table long time before. now i would like to add a new `user_id` column for table lessons,which refer the `id` on `users` table.

first i created the `add_profile_to_lessons` migration file and added the code to create a new column.

The `lessons` table

```php
if ( !Schema::hasTable('lessons') ) {
    Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('course_id', '54419_596eedbb6686e')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();
        $table->string('lesson_image')->nullable();
        $table->text('short_text')->nullable();
        $table->text('full_text')->nullable();
        $table->integer('position')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('free_lesson')->nullable()->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('published')->nullable()->default(0);

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->index(['deleted_at']);
    });
}
```

The `users` table

```php
if ( !Schema::hasTable('users') ) {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

The schema i created to add a new column in `add_profile_to_lessons` migration file

```php
Schema::table('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->after('course_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

When i executed php artisan migrate command, i get this error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`quicklms`.`#sql-d94_102`, CONSTR   AINT
>   `lessons_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`
>   (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `lessons` add constraint
>   `lessons_u   ser_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references
>   `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: you have your foreign key to not be null, what value should it be using for `user_id` for all the existing 'lessons' records?

Comment: If there are some rows in lessons table already you have to either create the user_id as nullable, set it's default value to some existing id of user or set the value of user_id for each row before creating a foreign key. If you don't do that, the user_id is filled with 0 for existing rows and that id doesn't exist in user table so foreign key constraint cannot be created.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266089/laravel-migration-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a/51474101#51474101

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migration - Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266089/laravel-migration-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a)

Comment: @MichalHynčica you are correct

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. What happens is when i executed the command i have seen the user_id column was created and it assigns all the values as zero.

so first i change the user_id value zero to some existing values in the users table. 
Then i place the below code in  `add_profile_to_lessons` migration file and excecuted the command `php artisan migrate` and it works ^_^

```
Schema::table('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```